# Fetch nested tags in php using simplehtmldom

Tags: php, html

Lets say I have this code. I want to fetch all p tag data from nested div tag. there can be 15 nested div tag. so want to write a script which can dig all the div and return p tag data from it.

```
<div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <p>Hello</p>
 </div>
<p>Hey</p>
</div>
```

required output(any order): 
Hi
Hello
Hey

I have attempted the following:

```
function divDigger($div)
{
    $internalP = $div->getElementsByTagName('p');
    echo $internalP->innertext;
    $internalDiv = $div->getElementsByTagName('div');
    if (count($internalDiv) > 0) {
        foreach ($internalDiv as $div) {
            divDigger($div);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [XPath API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) for this:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($yourHtml);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//div//p') as $pWithinDiv) {
  echo $pWithinDiv->textContent, PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will find any `<p>` element under a `<div>` (not necessarily directly under it, otherwise you can change the expression to `//div/p`), and display its text content.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/43QqX**

Comment: What changes I need to make to fetch data of all the tags of a website. I want all text data from all the tags @Jeto

Comment: @parthagrawal Try `//*` if you want all elements (but keep in mind that you're gonna get the same text multiple times), or `//*[not(*)]` if you want only leaf tags (but then you might miss some text if some of them contain both text and subtags).

Comment: Thanks a lot. By the way is there any way to get only footer section content?